# Server Resource Monitoring with New Relic and Heroku

Tags: heroku, newrelic

I am using Heroku and New Relic and am trying to get more detailed information on the servers resources, CPU usage, RAM etc.

New Relic has a section "Get started with Server Monitoring" but the instructions to set it up require working with the command line

running commands like apt-get install newrelic-sysmond and stuff.

How can I set this up with heroku?

Thanks!

EDIT

Here is the screen I am talking about.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxhG7.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The New Relic Linux / Windows Server Monitor agents are not able to used on Heroku.

You can get some memory info with this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics

Edit: Oh yeah, we also have an Instances tab:
http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/03/07/new-relics-instances-tab/

Comment: Aw bummer. Thanks for the info. Will utilize the instance tab.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to install NR monitoring via apt-get if you are using Heroku.

Are you saying that the NR monitoring isn't working at all, or are you just trying to get it to provide more information?

After installing the NR add-on, did you follow the configuration instructions for your language/environment? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. I already have the regular Application monitoring setup. I am talking about the Server monitoring which there is a tab for on the dash. I have attached a screenshot of the screen I am looking at on my original post. Thanks!

Comment: NP. The comments above by Brian from NR are right.  That tab/section isn't meant to be used when you're on Heroku; you should use the Instances tab instead.

Although, if you did have some traditional servers, their monitoring could be integrated into this dashboard if you used the API key from your Heroku-based account in the config for the monitoring of those servers. Then the data would be collected in the same place as your Heroku account.